# How bad is this quartz countertop seam (color mismatch)?

Tags: quartz

[image]Reality check here. The seam fits together quite well, but my wife and I were unpleasantly surprised by the degree of the color mismatch. Is that considered normal?

Comment: No good...........

Comment: This is likely to be closed as "opinion based", since that's what you're asking for. If it's unacceptable _to you_, ask the installer to fix it. If it's acceptable _to you_, move on with life. Whether I, a random stranger on the internet, would be willing to live with it or not is irrelevant in your decision making. That said, my opinion is no, that's totally unacceptable.

Comment: My opinion: unacceptable.

Comment: (not a native speaker) are you talking about the color of the product that connects the two pieces (like a seam between two pieces of fabric), if so I do not even see it. If this is the rectangular piece of a completely different color I would never accept then yes, they are completely mismatched.

Comment: Not unusual.  I'm guessing the workman gets to the site and finds the pieces badly mismatched.  Rather than go back to the shop to find the right bits he just installs what he has and hopes the customer doesn't complain.  (Note that in some cases, with large counters, there may be several pieces, and it's hard to get everything matched, especially if a piece breaks on-site and a substitute piece is needed.)

Comment: Noting the risk that this question be closed as being subjective, I'd suggest that it could be recast along the lines of "how much difference in terms of RAL or Pantone colours is considered acceptable in this situation?".

Comment: Do note that there appears to be a significant variation in the color across the larger piece.  The problem is that variation like this is fairly common.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is, in my opinion at least, quite substandard.  It looks as though they put two pieces from different batches together.

Seams are almost inevitable but they should carefully match pieces so that they are nearly invisible.  I'll bet that if you were to go to their showroom and look at some seams you'd have a difficult time figuring out that there was a seam there.

I'd absolutely have a discussion with the company that sold and installed this.  It's UNACCEPTABLE!

Comment: Yeah, that's not a "seam" problem, that's One from color A, One from color B on either side of the seam.

Comment: Agreed, that's unacceptable.  Get it re-done or a discount if you are willing to live with it.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson: Sometimes if one can't make things match perfectly, a good alternative (with the purchaser's permission) is to turn the mismatch into a design feature).  If the area is a breakfast bar, then although one would want a smooth top surface across the seam for ease of cleaning, having a deliberately contrasting color might look good.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is COMPLETELY unacceptable, and whoever installed it knows that. Ask him if he would accept that level of workmanship in his own house. He wouldn't, and neither should you. If you haven't paid for it yet, I would arrange to put the money in escrow until it is remedied. A big hassle, but better than living with that inferior product.